# Inserting "large" amounts of data into MySQL and the benefits of using a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm not sure how to store or insert this data.  I am using PHP and MySQL.

Let's say we're trying to keep track of people who enter marathons (like jogging or whatever).  So far, I have a `Person` table that has all my person information.  Each person happens to be associated with a unique varchar(40) key.  There is a table for the marathon information (`Marathon`).  I receive the person data in an CSV that as about 130,000 rows and import that into the database.

So - now the question is... how do I deal with that association between Person and Marathon?  For each Marathon, I get a huge list of participants (by that unique varchar key) that I need to import.  So... If I go the foreign key route, it seems like the insert would be very heavy and cumbersome to look up the appropriate foreign key for the person.  I'm not even sure how I would write that insert... I guess it would look like this:

```
insert  into person_marathon 

select  p.person_id, m.marathon_id

from    ( select 'person_a' as p_name, 'marathon_a' as m_name union 
          select 'person_b' as p_name, 'marathon_a' as m_name ) 
          as imported_marathon_person_list 

        join person p 
           on p.person_name = imported_marathon_person_list.p_name

        join marathon m 
           on m.marathon_name = imported_marathon_person_list.m_name
```

There are not a lot of marathons to deal with at one time.  There a lot of people, though.

**-->** Should I even give the person an ID and require all the foreign keys? or just use the unique varchar(40) as the true table key?  But then I would have to join tables on a varchar and that's bad.  A marathon can have anywhere from 1k to 30k participants.

**-->** Or, I could select the person info and the marathon info from the database and join it with the marathon_person data in PHP before I send it over to MySQL.

**-->** Or, I guess, maybe make a temporary table, then join in the db, then insert (through PHP)?  It's been already strongly suggested that I do not use temporary tables ever (this is a work thing and this isn't my database).

**Edit:  I am not sure on what schema to use because I'm not sure if I should be using foreign keys or not** (purpose of this whole post is to answer that question) but the basic design would be something like...

```
create table person ( 
    person_id int unisgned auto_incrememnt, 
    person_key varchar(40) not null, 
    primary key (person_id),
    constraint uc_person_key unique (person_key)
)

create table marathon (
    marathon_id int unisgned auto_incrememnt, 
    marathon_name varchar(60) not null, 
    primary key (marathon_id) 
)

create table person_marathon (
    person_marathon_id int unsigned auto_increment,
    person_id int unsigned,
    marathon_id int unsigned,  
    primary key (person_marathon_id),
    constraint uc_person_marathon unique (person_id, marathon_id), 
    foreign key person_id references person (person_id),
    foreign key marathon_id references marathon (marathon_id)
)
```

I'm going to repeat the actual question really quick.... If I choose to use a foreign key for `person`, how do I import all the person_marathon data with the person_id in an efficient way?  The insert statement I included above is my best guess....

The `person` data comes in a CSV of about 130,000 rows so that is a straight import into the person table.  The person data comes with a unique varchar(40) for each person.

The `person_marathon` data comes in a CSV for each marathon, as a list of 1,000 to 30,000 unique varchar(40)'s that represent each person who participated in that marathon.

**Summary:  I am using PHP.  So what is the best way to write the insert/import of the person_marathon data if I am using foreign keys?**  Would I have to do it like the insert statement above or is there a better way?

Comment: Post the current db schema you are using.

Answer (score -1):

This is a many-to-many relationship, one person can enter many marathons, one marathon can be entered by many persons. You need additional table in your data model to track this relation, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE persons_marathons(
  personID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id),
  marathonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Marathons(M_Id)
)
```

This table uses foreign key constraints. The foreign key constraint prevents from inserting bad data (for example you cannot insert a row with personID = 123 when there is no such id in Persons table), it prevents also from deletes that would destroy a link between tables (for example you cannot delete a person X when exists a record in person_marathon table witth such personID).

If this table contains the following rows:

```
personID  | MarathonID
----------+-----------
    2     |  3
    3     |  3
    2     |  8
    3     |  8
```

it means that persons 2 and 3 both entered marathons 3 and 8

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but I don't think you understood my post/question... The example insert statement I wrote shows a person_marathon table that has the person_id and marathon_id in it.  The question wasn't about how to use foreign keys.